# how to match the end part in text using regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have text file format like below:

```
[foo]
foo1=1
foo2=2

[goo]
goo1=1
goo2=2

[bar]
bar1=1
bar2=2
```

The goal is to extract the whole list out given the header name. For example, given the header name `foo`, using regex `\[foo\](?:.|\s)+?\[` I can extract foo and its following list. given `goo` and regex `\[goo\](?:.|\s)+?\[` I can extrct `goo` and its list. like [shown in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yU7bX1/2)

perl implementation:

```
sub getListOfSettingFromKey {
    my $key  = shift;
    my $text = shift;
    my $pattern = "\\[$key\\](?:.|\\s)+?\\[";
    my $regex   = qr/$pattern/;
    if ($text =~ $regex) {
        return $&;
    }
    return "";
}
```

However, this way apply to all but the last part, `bar` in this example since there is no match `[` at the end. then how to match the last part?

Comment: I don't understand why so many downvotes. there are both code sample and example and it's a programming question about regular expression.

Comment: `my $regex   = qr/\[$key\][^\[]+/`

Comment: I suspect the issue is that you should know not to process standard config files using regex patterns. You should also avoid avoid reading an entire file into memory unless you need to, and using `$&` is very inefficient except on more recent versions of Perl

Comment: that works. Thank you! what do you suggest if the format of this config cannot be changed? @Borodin

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Why would you need to change it?

Comment: @Borodin you mentioned "not to process standard config files using regex patterns". what do you suggest given this format of the config? and do you mind submit an answer about what the perl function should be?

Comment: Okay, what I meant was that you have a standard config file there, and there are [ridiculously many modules on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?m=module&q=config+ini&s=11) that deal with such files. [**stevieb's** solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32216207/622310) using [`Config::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Tiny) is quite adequate. It is very easy to write something using regex patterns that mostly works but lets you down when it most matters

Comment: @Borodin got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a regex, but Perl's [`Config::Tiny`](http://search.cpan.org/~rsavage/Config-Tiny-2.22/lib/Config/Tiny.pm) is perfect for reading (and writing) these "ini" types of files.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Config::Tiny;

my $conf = Config::Tiny->read('data.txt');

print "$conf->{bar}{bar2}\n";
```

Comment: I think you should have stuck with your `Config::Tiny` solution. The alternative assumes a lot about the data that we can't be sure of

Comment: Agreed, fixed. Thanks Borodin.

Comment: Of course `Config::Tiny` will make some similar assumptions, but at least it's someone else's fault!

Comment: LOL. Yes, I agree. I was just trying to fit with the OP's regex desire, but most of the time we're dealing with an XY Problem anyhow. `Config::Tiny` is clearly the obvious choice unless there's some compelling reason to re-invent the wheel here.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate what you were aiming for, and the guts of the module probably looks similar. It's also worth considering the scenario where the OP is unable to install modules on their system, whether that is through a prohibition, a lack of skill, or a shortage of imagination. For some reason there are a surprising number of people in that situation, and a homebrew solution is the only option because as far as I know there are no core config modules. I have advocated copying module code and passing it off as the programmer's own, but I don't think anyone has taken up my suggestion

Answer (score -1):

I did not understand your question, however, you can try one of the following patterns in order to achieve your requirements:

- `/(?:\[?(?:foo|bar)\]?(?:\d\=\d)?)/g` will match both **foo** & **bar** (included the properties)
- `/(?:\[?foo\]?(?:\d\=\d)?)/g` will only match **foo** including it's properties.
- `/(?:\[?foo\]?(?:\d\=\d)?|\[bar\])/g` will match **foo** including it's properties and **bar**

### Update #1

Use the following pattern: `/(\[(?:foo|bar|goo)\](?:(?!\[(?:foo|bar|goo)\])[\s\S])*)/g`

Comment: I added more explanation. any questions now?

Comment: Then use the following pattern **/(?:\[?(?:foo|bar|goo)\]?(?:\d\=\d)?)/g**, take a look at: https://regex101.com/r/qC5zT7/1

Comment: foo, bar or goo is the parameter to the regex, each time given the parameter, the regex function will return the list. more questions?

Comment: @qqibrow: Please take a look at the update on the answer.